# com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

Tags: android, eclipse, android-gradle-plugin

I'm migrated eclipse android project to android studio which has the `targetSdkVersion` 19. Now, I'm changed`targetSdkVersion` to 23. Now the problem is Gradle shows error after adding `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1` into dependencies.

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:assembleDebug]
C:\Users\madhanhere\stories-android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml
Error:(190) Attribute "theme" has already been defined
Error:(190) Attribute "theme" has already been defined
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
Information:BUILD FAILED
```

My app.gradle file:

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "21.0.1"
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ebooks.stories"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/core.jar')
    compile files('libs/logentries-android-2.1.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.2.0.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.+'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
}
```

values.xml file:

```
<declare-styleable name="WalletFragmentOptions"><attr format="enum" name="theme">
            <enum name="holo_dark" value="0"/>
            <enum name="holo_light" value="1"/>
        </attr><attr format="enum" name="environment">
            <enum name="production" value="1"/>
            <enum name="sandbox" value="0"/>
            <enum name="strict_sandbox" value="2"/>
        </attr><attr format="reference" name="fragmentStyle"/><attr format="enum" name="fragmentMode">
            <enum name="buyButton" value="1"/>
            <enum name="selectionDetails" value="2"/>
        </attr></declare-styleable>
```

How can I solve this any solution?

Comment: try to use buildToolsVersion starting with 23

Comment: @Nabeel Tried buildToolsVersion "23.0.3" but it gives me the same error.

Comment: @NabeelK thanks for your effort issue solved by change com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.+ and buildToolsVersion "23.0.3".

Comment: you are welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to update `play-services version` and `buildToolsVersion`. I solved the problem by changing updating `play-serivces` to

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.+
```

and `buildToolsVersion` to

```
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
```